# move dynamic range of data seperated by blank to new column in separate tab

Tags: vba, excel, csv, dynamic, copy-paste

I have almost 0 experience with VBA. I have searched everywhere and hope someone can help. I have a .csv created by a ixchariot script. I am trying to 1st separate the data in column P into its groups which is a dynamic range for each output of the .csv  (eg. 1st run will and group of colump P will be P1-P68, 2nd will be P1-P100) and then move each group into its own column in a separate tab (eg. group 1 column A, group 2 column B). To separate in groups I use column B which has group numbers 1 through x) script looks like this...

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
'Update 20140716
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,      Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
    WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

so I have the separation of the groups but how to move the dynamic range of groups from column p to the new tab and then into the separate columns?

[separating into groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8J1f.jpg)

[desired output in separate tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZObQ.jpg)

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can cut/copy cells and paste visible cells into a new location.  Depending on your filtering of the data, you can loop your filtering process for each unique group, find the new last row for each, and copy from P2:P & lastrow.  You would redim your last row in the loop, or just have a defined range and only work with visible cells.

Comment: Thank you Cyril for the direction. I will have to do some reading to implement but will post my code as I go.

Comment: If you can utilize another sheet, it might help to copy column P, remove all duplicates, then give yourself an exact list to loop through.  I can try to add some code to help out.  Just gave some input early in case it wasn't the right kind of info for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's move column P

```
Sheets("PrimarySheet").Range("P:P").Copy
Sheets("AnotherSheet").Range("A:A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I'm kind of crappy about this, but delete rows for each duplicate entry

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = Cells(Sheets("AnotherSheet").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 to LR
    If Cells(i,1)=Cells(i+1,1) Then
        Sheets("AnotherSheet").Rows(i+1).Delete
        Else:
        End If
Next i
```

Now, you'll want to go back to your main sheet and sort the total range based on Column P , looping through that list on another sheet (this is the part where I need to start looking stuff up more, so it won't be complete code... I will be editing)

```
Dim j as Integer
Dim LR1 as Long
LR1 = Cells(Sheets("PrimarySheet").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LR1 as Long
For j = 1 to LR1

With Sheets("PrimarySheet")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Columns(16).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=    Sheets("AnotherSheet").Cells(j,1).Value
End With

Redim LR1 as Long
Sheets("PrimarySheet").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(LR1)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = Sheets("AnotherSheet").Cells(j,1).Value
Sheets(Cells(j,1).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next j
```

Hopefully this is a decent start for you, if not enough to finish your work!

Comment: thank you Cyril. Im trying to implement now. I will have more time to dig into this over the weekend. I don't need to parse duplicates as its time based performance data but thanks for that snippit!